# Django Login Required to view

Tags: python, django

I am building a small application which needs user profiles, I've used the build in user system from Django. But I have a problem regarding that even if you are not logged in you can still view the profile also another thing is that each user should only see his profile not others I need some tips on this

views.py

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = get_user_model()
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = "user_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user = super(UserProfileDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user

class UserProfileEditView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "edit_profile.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)[0]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user})
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the `Class Based Generic View`, you need to add decorator `@login_required` in your `urls.py`

```
#urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from app_name import views

url(r'^test/$', login_required(views.UserProfileDetailView.as_view()), name='test'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the `login_required` decorator? [Docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator).

Since it seems you are using Class Based Views, you need to decorate in the urlconf, [see here for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views).

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can add `LoginRequiredMixin` for your custom view.
Example:

```
class MyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView): # LoginRequiredMixin MUST BE FIRST
    pass
```

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin

Answer (score -3):

The below is what you should typically do

```
@login_required
def my_view(request, uid):
    # uid = user id taken from profile url
    me = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    if me != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do it for Django CBV.

Comment: In CBV, can't he just use @login_rquired on dispatch method?

Comment: That would mean overriding every method (if he's using views from other apps), just to add a decorator and call the superimplementation. Very untidy.